# Is there a standard Backus-Naur form for checking that lists contain consistent token types?

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex, bnf, ply

I'm using [PLY](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply) to parse [DNET files](https://www.norsys.com/downloads/DNET_File_Format.txt). Part of the grammar suggested by the DNET specification is (in my words):

```
<value>  -> NUMBER | STRING | ID
<values> -> <value> | <values> COMMA <value>
<list>   -> LPAREN <values> RPAREN | LPAREN RPAREN
```

This works fine if I don't care about mixing token types within a list. However, if I want to be sure that the parser only produces valid lists, it would be great if I could guarantee consistent token types within the list.

My intuition was to define a list production for each valid union of token types, and then use that list production where needed. For example, if I wanted to guarantee I have a list of `STRING` tokens:

```
<strings>     -> STRING | <strings> COMMA STRING
<string_list> -> LPAREN <strings> RPAREN | LPAREN RPAREN
```

But this means I would have to define a bajillion different list productions. Is there a smarter way to do this at the parser level, or should I save this sort of validation to be executed on the AST that I build?

Comment: That sort of type checking is usually deferred to the semantic analysis phase (after the AST is built). Having the grammar do all the specializations tends to get messy (and sometimes can't be done at all).

Comment: Thank you. I really needed to hear someone say it <3